# Open Lightning component in a popup

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have 2 lightning component. One component contains a button and another component needs to be opened in a popup on click of the button in first component.I don't have the code to open the second component in a popup.Need your help on this

Comment: The [SLDS Popovers](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/popovers/) classes such as `slds-popover slds-popover--panel` will provide the look and then adding [Visibility](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/visibility/#flavor-hide-show) classes from the JavaScript controller can do the show/hide.

Comment: Have you checked existing questions/answers before posting this question? There is a very similar [question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115092/how-to-display-modal-popup-with-a-form-inside-a-lightning-component) to your requirement. Kindly check that out first and then let us know if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
BulkReply: function(component, event, helper){

 var modalBody;

 var lstEmails=component.get('v.lstEmails');

 console.log('lstEmails---' + lstEmails);

 $A.createComponent("c:EmailComponent", {lstEmails:lstEmails},

 function(content, status) {

   if (status === "SUCCESS") {


  modalBody = content;

     component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({

    header: "Bulk Reply",

    body: modalBody, 

     showCloseButton: true,


     closeCallback: function() {

                                           }
                                       })
                                   }                               
                               });
        }

    },
```

also use `lightning:overlaylibrary` in component in which button are there